# linux command fails with alloc magic is broken at 0xXXXXX

Tags: linux, grub2, macintosh, bootable

I have problems booting into my MacBookPro9,2

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

When I try to boot manually I can set the root to (hd1,3) which is the partition I have for Ubuntu.

I can’t proceed to boot because when I type:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
```

Or

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-38-generic
```

I get the following error:

alloc magic is broken at (some address) 
Then my computer restarts automatically.

Any idea of what could be wrong here?

Is it grub2 ?
Is it the kernel?

**Edit:**

Before installing Ubuntu i has MacOS but I had a problem with APFS corruption. I decided I’ve had enough of Apple and decided to switch to Ubuntu.

The number changes each time.

Right know my partition table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Does the number change? If not share it here. I have no idea, but often these thinks can help. I often see people hold back what they see as not relevant, but it is. **Hope you get some help, and welcome**

Comment: Is this a fresh install?  Have you upgraded recently?  I'm assuming you have a dual-boot setup as per your config above.  What were the circumstances in which this occurred?

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be booting from (hd0,1) or (hd0,2)?  From the looks of things, you don't have a second drive (i.e. sdb) so (hd1,3) would reference a non-existent drive....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the attention. I tried booting and then installing several distributions. The problem seems to be hardware-related. Either a bad SATA cable or my new Samsung EVO 1TB SSD.

I'll be working with Slax Linux in the future, that way I can keep everything on my usb.